# Django Maximum Value From Merged Table Columns

Tags: django, join, merge, union, annotate

I am trying to get the maximum value from merging the results from two separate tables.  I am trying to get the most updated comment for a Post.  I have a model `Comment` that can be accessed by `Post.comments`.  I also have a body that is separate of the `Post` that can be accessed by `Post.body`.  Both comments and body have a field `when` that is a `DateTimeField`.  I would like to return a sorted queryset by most recent activity such that the a Post with the most recent comment or body is shown first.

Assume the models look like this:

```
class Body(models.Model):
    when = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)

class Post(models.Model):
    body = models.ForeignKey(Body)

class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='comments')
    when = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
```

I would like the result to remain a queryset if possible since I continue to process it and further pass it into a paginator to limit results.

Basically, I would like to be able to call:

```
q = Post.annotate(
    activity=Max(
        Union('comments__when', 'body__when')
    )
)
q = q.order_by('-activity')
```

But I don't know how to accomplish that Union.

I believe the SQL that accomplishes what I'm looking for is comparable to:

```
SELECT
...
IF(MAX(c.`when`), MAX(c.`when`), b.`when`) AS `activity`
...
FROM `post` p
...
LEFT OUTER JOIN `comment` AS c
ON c.`post_id`=p.`id`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `body` AS b
ON p.`body_id`=b.`id`
...
```

Can such a customized annotation and Join be accomplished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This took me an extremely long time to figure out.  One large issue is that Django does not support multiple conditions for the `ON` clause of a `JOIN` statement.  Because of the dependence of a single `SELECT` statement upon two separate `JOINs`, we have an issue tracking the table names accurately.  When you ask django to annotate a table, say with `Max()`, you end up with conditions such as `Max(T7.when) ... LEFT OUT JOIN table AS T7`, where T7 is not consistent.  Thus, I needed a way to accruately generate the expression `Max(T7.when)` given the `JOINs` automatically generated by Django.  Many posts online tell you to use the `.raw()` support on querysets, but you'll lose a lot of benefit from using an ORM in this case.

The solution I came up with was to generate a custom aggregate function.  I called this function `CustomMax()`:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models

sum_if_sql_template = 'GREATEST(%(alt_table)s.%(alt_field)s, IFNULL(%(function)s(%(field)s), %(alt_table)s.%(alt_field)s))'

class CustomMaxSQL(models.sql.aggregates.Aggregate):
    sql_function = 'MAX'
    sql_template = sum_if_sql_template


class CustomMax(models.aggregates.Aggregate):
    name = 'Max'

    def __init__(self, lookup, **extra):
        self.lookup = lookup
        self.extra = extra

    def add_to_query(self, query, alias, col, source, is_summary):
        aggregate = CustomMaxSQL(col,
                             source=source,
                             is_summary=is_summary,
                             **self.extra)
        query.aggregates[alias] = aggregate
```

The usage of the function is:

```
q = Post.annotate(
    activity=CustomMax(
        'comments__when',
        alt_table="app_post",
        alt_field="when",
    )
)
q.query.join((
    'app_post',
    'app_comment',
    'id',
    'post_id',
))
q = q.order_by('-activity')
```

I include the `.join()` to allow for the alt_table to exist as a `JOIN`, and Django will automatically handle the naming of both the `SELECT` and `JOIN` statements for the `Max` portion.  The generated SQL from this usage is akin to:

```
SELECT 
...
GREATEST(app_post.when, IFNULL(MAX(T7.`when`), app_post.when)) AS `activity`,
...
`app_post`.`id`
...
INNER JOIN `app_post` ON ...
...
LEFT OUTER JOIN `app_comment` T7 ON (`app_post`.`id` = T7.`post_id`)
...
```

Note: This is just for `Post` and `Comment` models from above.  My actual implementation was a bit more complicated and required this solution.

This would also have been a lot easier if the Django team had developed this suggested patch to include `join` statements in `.extra()`: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/7231